# how to alert when the time has ended in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to show alert when the time has ended and the timer should stop running i have tried the following code the but timer keeps on running and it does not show any alert messsge help me

```
      <script>
 function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 *0.10,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
if(startTimer<0)
{
    alert("time has ended");
}

});
  </script>
<div style="float-left">Test Will Ends in <span id="time">10:00</span>
```

Comment: [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Comment: need show alert and the timer has to stop when the time has ended but the timer keeps on running from the start and didnt show any alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to *attach* the interval to a variable, like:

```
interval = setInterval(function() { ... }, 1000);
```

Then you check for time to end and use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval):

```
if (--timer < 0) {
    timer = duration;
    window.alert("Time's up!");
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6bc4pp33/3/)

Comment: could please help me  after the alert has shown i need to submit the form can you give me idea to do that

Comment: @ArunKumaresh just use `$("#form").submit()` or `jQuery("#form").submit()` inside the `if` block. `"#form"` should be a valid selector to get your form element.

Comment: on submit i have to record the how much time has been spent can please give me idea to get how much time spent when the button has been clicked

Comment: @ArunKumaresh you can add a `hidden` input to your form, and set the time to it before calling `.submit()`. Got it ?

Comment: actually i have got answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624342/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-count-timer-on-button-click/35624605?noredirect=1#comment58931905_35624605 how to get the time on button click button the thing is i dnt know how to pass the value using php to other page

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bbhh3px8/ when see here the <div id="runtimes"> contains the value but i dnt know how to pass using the post

Comment: @ArunKumaresh you need an input inside the form. Do you know how to post data with forms? Like `<input type='hidden' name='time' id='time' />` and `$("#time").val(currentTime)`, then `$("#form").submit()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104533/discussion-between-arun-kumaresh-and-dontvotemedown).

Comment: @ArunKumaresh I'm afraid this is another subject, another question. The current question has been answered. I suggest you to create another question instead of start a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 *10,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("text!!!!");        // this will show the alert popup
            clearInterval(interval);  // this will stop the timer
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: need show alert and the timer has to stop when the time has ended but the timer keeps on running from the start and didnt show any alert