# how to get the value of the count timer on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

```
<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
     interval = setInterval(function () {
          minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
          seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

          minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
          seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

          display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

         if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("Time has ended");
            $("#registration-form").submit()
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, 1000);
}

 jQuery(function ($) {
    s=10;
    var Minutes = 60 * s,
    isplay = $('#time');
    startTimer(Minutes, display);
});
</script>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="test" >Time Left <span id="time"></span>min</div>
</div>

<form name="frmRegistration" id="registration-form" method="post">
  <input class="btnAction" type="submit" name="finish" id="finish" value="Finish" onclick="clearInterval(interval)" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

This is my countdown timer when the page loads the timer will start when i click the button  i should get the value of how many minutes the timer has run for example if the timer is run for 2 min i should get the value as 2 min and i want it store it in the database i have tried the following but it doesnt work please hlep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most reliable way would be to store the date the timer started in a variable, then get the difference between that date and the current date when the button is clicked, something like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var seconds = (now.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
    $('#runtimes').append('<p>' + seconds + '</p>');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bbhh3px8/)

This shows the value in seconds, but this can easily be converted to minutes and rounded up or down as you require.

Comment: ya it showing in seconds can you please tell how can i convert it into minutes

Comment: `var minutes = seconds / 60` I would guess you want to use `Math.floor()` on that to round it down.

Comment: i need to pass this value through the post to other page is it possible to get this value through other page

Comment: Yes, you can use any standard method eg. put it in localStorage, add it to the querystring, send it in AJAX etc. If you have an issue with that I would suggest starting a new question.